# How can I convert MP4 video files to DVD?

Tags: windows, video, conversion, dvd, mp4

I've got some MP4 video files that I'd like to put onto DVD. What is the best software (preferably free) for accomplishing such a task?

Comment: If it's just for personal use, check your dvd player first. Mine can play mp4 files on a disc, but I don't know how common that is (mine has a logo on the front saying so).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DVDFlick](http://www.dvdflick.net/), an Open Source product:

> DVD Flick aims to be a simple but at
>   the same time powerful DVD Authoring
>   tool. It can take a number of video
>   files stored on your computer and turn
>   them into a DVD that will play back on
>   your DVD player, Media Center or Home
>   Cinema Set. You can add additional
>   custom audio tracks, subtitles as well
>   as a menu for easier navigation.

Answer (score 7):

For a commercial product, [ConvertXtoDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/) is great.

For a free solution try converting with [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) then use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se/?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, which I use and would recommend is [**Freemake Video Converter**](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) and is also freeware.

Simply open the application, drag MP4 videos into the window and hit the "to DVD" button.  Pretty simple stuff and the results are excellent.

> DVD Burning
>
> Unlike other software, our video converter doesn't have a two-hour limit and allows to burn up to 20 hours of video to a Standard DVD or 40 hours to DVD-DL. Apply different DVD menu types: thumbnail, motion, text.

[image]

Comment: Freemake Video Converter now has a watermark it adds to the DVD.