# Convert .MKV to video-dvd.ISO

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, dvd, iso-image, matroska

I'm trying to convert an MKV (matroska) file to an ISO file for a video-DVD.

I looked up a lot of information about DVD and how to get a .vob working but I failed every time.

I tied to extract all the subfiles of the MKV file and tried to do something with that but I didn't know how.

I have the following MKV file

```
Film.mkv

track 1: video: MPEG4/ISO/AVC h.264
track 2, 3, 4: audio: AC3 or AAC
track 5, 6, ...: subtitles: SRT or ASS|SSA or VOBSUB
```

I need to be able to select an audio and a subtitle track with the DVD-player. Is there a way to make a video-DVD out of this? the more I search for answers to more I get confused.

What is the best way to do this? or some GUI application that is able to do this. If you give command line steps. pleas try to give some explanation.

(I know how to work with a command line) (I run Debian Jessie)

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/44207/how-can-i-convert-mp4-video-files-to-dvd

Comment: Thanks but it's all windows, I'd like to just use GNU/Linux if possible.

Comment: Okay then https://superuser.com/questions/23465/scriptable-dvd-authoring-solution-for-linux